# Slimphp log from middleware

Tags: php, slim

I have the following set up in a Slim PHP project using Monolog for logging but cannot log from middleware.

In dependdencies.php I have

```
$container['logger'] = function ($c) {
    $settings = $c->get('settings')['logger'];
    $logger = new Monolog\Logger($settings['name']);
    $logger->pushProcessor(new Monolog\Processor\UidProcessor());
    $logger->pushHandler(new Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler($settings['path'], $settings['level']));
    return $logger;
};
```

Then in middleware.php I have

```
use App\Middleware\Logging;
$app->add(new Logging($container->logger));
```

With App\Middleware\Logging being:

```
<?php

namespace App\Middleware;

class Logging
{

public function __construct($logger)
{
    $this->logger = $logger;
}

public function __invoke($request, $response, $next)
{
    $routeParams = $request->getAttribute('routeInfo')[2];
    $this->logger->info($request->getMethod() . " -- " . $request->getUri());
    return $next($request, $response);
}
}
```

How can I then log from another middleware file?

I also have App/Middleware/CacheMiddleware

```
<?php

namespace  App\Middleware;

use Psr\Http\Message\RequestInterface;
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface;

class CacheMiddleware
{
public function __invoke(RequestInterface $request, ResponseInterface $response, callable $next)
{
    //$this->logger->info('test');
    $response->getBody()->write('BEFORE');
    return $next($request, $response);
}
}
```

But I get an error `Call to a member function info() on null`

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, class `CacheMiddleware` has no member `$logger`. In class `Logging` you pass a logger instance to the constructor and set `$this->logger` accordingly, but in `CacheMiddleware` you don't.
Do the same in the other class:

```
class CacheMiddleware
{

    public function __construct($logger)
        {
            $this->logger = $logger;
        }
    // rest of class definition
}
```

and when you add a new instance of `CacheMiddleware` to the app middlewares, pass `$container['logger']` to the constructor like you did with `$app->add(new Logging($container->logger));` :

```
$app->add(new CacheMiddleware($container->logger));
```